# MsBuild and MsDeploy problems

Tags: msbuild, publish, msdeploy

When I publish web project by gui(VS2010) (right click in project and choose Publish menu item, publish Method - Web Deploy) - everything works fine.

Problems appear when I am trying to publish via command line: MSBUILD or MsDeploy.

With MSBuild a package is created with no publishing (only creating package):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSbuild.exe" Project.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTraget=MSDeployPublish /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:MSDeployServiceUrl=https://[ip]/msdeploy.axd /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true  /p:DeployIisAppPath=NlbTestSite /p:UserName=M\DeployUser /p:Password=qwerty
```

With MsDeploy i get an error: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

```
E:\Work\OutDir\MSDeploy\Package.deploy.cmd" /Y /M:"https://[ip]:8172/msdeploy.axd" /U:"M\DeployUser" /P:"qwerty" -allowUntrusted /A:Basic
```

My goal is to automate the deployment process using one of those methods.

I want to find out how Visual Studio publishes my project (what command with what arguments)?

**UPDATE 19.10.2012 14:52**

When I add `/p:UseMsDeployExe=true`, `msdeploy.exe` is executed, but nothing is copied.

The execution command:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe -source:manifest='E:\[Path]\obj\Debug\Package\[Project].SourceManifest.xml' -dest:package='E:\[Path]\[Project]\obj\Debug\Package\[Project].zip',IncludeAcls='False' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -declareParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',kind='ProviderPath',scope='IisApp',match='^E:\\[Path]\\obj\\Debug\\Package\\PackageTmp$',defaultvalue='[SiteName]',tags='IisApp' -declareParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',kind='ProviderPath',scope='setAcl',match='^E:\\[Path]\\obj\\Debug\\Package\\PackageTmp$' -declareParam:name='Add write permission to App_Data Folder',kind='ProviderPath',scope='setAcl',match='^E:\\[Path]\\obj\\Debug\\Package\\PackageTmp\\App_Data$',description='Add write permission to App_Data folder',defaultvalue='{IIS Web Application Name}/App_Data',tags='Hidden' -declareParam:name='MainModelContainer-Web.config Connection String',kind='XmlFile',scope='E:\\[Path]\\OutDir\\temp\\Web\.config$',match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='MainModelContainer']/@connectionString",description='MainModelContainer Connection String used in web.config by the application to access the database.',defaultvalue='metadata=[ConnectionString]"',tags='SqlConnectionString' -declareParam:name='SimpleConnection-Web.config Connection String',kind='XmlFile',scope='E:\\[Path]\\OutDir\\temp\\Web\.config$',match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='SimpleConnection']/@connectionString",description='SimpleConnection Connection String used in web.config by the application to access the database.',defaultvalue='[ConnectionString]',tags='SqlConnectionString' -declareParam:name='ElmahDB-Web.config Connection String',kind='XmlFile',scope='E:\\[Path]\\OutDir\\temp\\Web\.config$',match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='ElmahDB']/@connectionString",description='ElmahDB Connection String used in web.config by the application to access the database.',defaultvalue='[ConnectionString]',tags='SqlConnectionString' -retryAttempts=2
```

No parameters, such as ComputerName, User or password are passed.
Any ideas about the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.
Got some ideas from http://root-project.org/work/net/automated-web-deployment-with-msbuild-and-msdeploy

I separated msbuild and msdeploy, and executed msdeploy explicitly.
Here is the template:

```
msdeploy.exe
-source:package=’C:\SomeWebProject\obj\Release\Package\SomeWebProject.zip‘
-dest:auto,ComputerName=’https://TargetServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=TargetWebSite‘,UserName=’Username‘,Password=’Password‘,IncludeAcls=’False’,AuthType=’Basic’
-verb:sync
-disableLink:AppPoolExtension
-disableLink:ContentExtension
-disableLink:CertificateExtension
-allowUntrusted
-retryAttempts=2
-setParam:’IIS Web Application Name’=’TargetWebSite/TargetWebApp‘
```

But problem with msbuild still remains.

Answer (score 1):

In your `pubxml` file, declare the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseMsDeployExe>true</UseMsDeployExe>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now when you deploy, you should see the call to `msdeploy.exe` in the publih log.

Make note, though, that it will actually be calling msdeploy.exe directly, and not via the generated `deploy.cmd` file.